# How to display the time with 'hours:minutes:seconds' in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I was spending lot of time for the answer of my question, but I've nothing found.

How can I display the time format in 'hours:minutes:seconds', ex.: 20:30:12? I've tried to change the locale from >time: "%H:%M"< to >time: "%H:%M:%S"< because I saw that %S is for seconds, but there is no effect :(

What I've done wrong?

Thanks for answers!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Time.now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
```

Answer (score 7):

Use Time#strftime method

In your case:

```
t = Time.now
t.strftime("%H:%M:%S")   #=> "12:09:34"
```

The different formats:

```
 %a - The abbreviated weekday name (``Sun'')
  %A - The  full  weekday  name (``Sunday'')
  %b - The abbreviated month name (``Jan'')
  %B - The  full  month  name (``January'')
  %c - The preferred local date and time representation
  %d - Day of the month (01..31)
  %H - Hour of the day, 24-hour clock (00..23)
  %I - Hour of the day, 12-hour clock (01..12)
  %j - Day of the year (001..366)
  %m - Month of the year (01..12)
  %M - Minute of the hour (00..59)
  %p - Meridian indicator (``AM''  or  ``PM'')
  %S - Second of the minute (00..60)
  %U - Week  number  of the current year,
          starting with the first Sunday as the first
          day of the first week (00..53)
  %W - Week  number  of the current year,
          starting with the first Monday as the first
          day of the first week (00..53)
  %w - Day of the week (Sunday is 0, 0..6)
  %x - Preferred representation for the date alone, no time
  %X - Preferred representation for the time alone, no date
  %y - Year without a century (00..99)
  %Y - Year with century
  %Z - Time zone name
  %% - Literal ``%'' character
```

And then you can create formats like that:

```
t = Time.now
   t.strftime("Printed on %m/%d/%Y")   #=> "Printed on 04/09/2003"
   t.strftime("at %I:%M%p")            #=> "at 08:56AM"
```